# Export excel range as a new excel sheet with save as dialog box

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, vba

I want to create a button in excel sheet which will copy a particular range(named range) and then open a Save As dialog box and user can select the location and save that range as a new excel sheet. Is this possible?

I am able to write a code which copies the named range to clipboard and then user can paste it into MS word etc. Below is the code I have till now.

```
Sub copyValueTable()
  Dim oRange As Range
  Set oRange = Sheets("Analysis").Range("FullValueTable")
  oRange.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
  oRange.Copy
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
Sub copyValueTable()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Please select the range" & vbNewLine & "Enter named range", Type:=8)

    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="xls Files (*.xls), *.xls")
        If fileSaveName <> False Then

            ActiveSheet.Copy
            Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
            Set sht = wkb.Sheets(1)
            sht.Cells.Clear
            rng.Copy sht.Range("A1")

            wkb.SaveAs fileSaveName
            wkb.Close
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Santosh, your solution works but it is also saving all the objects(buttons, drop downs etc). What should I do?

Comment: Try `Sheet1.Cells.Delete` instead of `sht.Cells.Clear`

Comment: thanks for the swift reply. I tried it and now it is saving full sheet. previously it was saving the range and objects.

Comment: it is also copying the full sheet.. even the sheet name(analysis) is saving. I think it has something to do with ActiveSheet.Copy

Comment: Add sht.DrawingObjects.Delete after rng.Copy sht.Range("A1") in your answer. This will delete all the drawing objects from the sheet. Thanks Santosh

Comment: @antnewbee I was away so cannot reply. Its nice that you are able to figure out the issue. If the solution was helpful please accept the anwser.